# How to Point Cluster With Dynamic Data In ArcGIS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clustering

ArcGIS API is using [this Demo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html) to illustrate how Point clustering works with JSON data. In my case I am generating some point graphics from MySQL Database by a jQuery AJAX request like following code: As you can see I am storing the data in `project` and then access to `project.Longitude, project.Latitude` to create the points

```
request.done(function( mapInfo) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapInfo.length; i++) {
            var project = mapInfo[i];
            var point = new Point(project.Longitude, project.Latitude); 
            var pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(); 
            pointSymbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE);
            pointSymbol.setSize(12);
            var pointInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(); 
            pointInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
            pointInfoTemplate.setContent('//JSON Data');
            var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol).setInfoTemplate(pointInfoTemplate);
            points.push(pointGraphic);
}
for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        map.graphics.add(points[i]);
}
});`
```

How can I bind this points with Cluster Points in ArcGIS API sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code you have lat and lon. In the sample that you linked to, in the function `addClusters` is where you can use that same lat/lon:

[image: screenshot from https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html]

So basically if you follow the sample, putting in your lat/lon in the place I highlighted above, it should work for you.